# Project R: Extract same IDs, different values

Tags: r, extract

I have a data.frame df with 10 columns. The first column contains unique IDs. 
I want to extract all rows with where an ID occurs more than one time (so I guess I have to work with duplicate) but has different values in an other column.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(
         Cnty = rep(c("185", "31", "189"), times = c(5, 3, 2)),
         Yr = c(rep(c("1999", "2000"), times = c(3, 2)), 
                "1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", "2000"),
         Plt = "20001",
         Spp = sample(c("Bitternut", "Pignut", "WO"), 10, replace = TRUE),
         DBH = runif(10, 0, 15)
     )
```

The result will look like this:

```
   Cnty   Yr   Plt       Spp       DBH
1   185 1999 20001 Bitternut  3.089619
2   185 1999 20001    Pignut  2.648351
3   185 1999 20001    Pignut 10.305343
4   185 2000 20001        WO  5.761556
5   185 2000 20001 Bitternut 11.547621
6    31 1999 20001        WO  7.465489
7    31 1999 20001        WO 10.764278
8    31 2000 20001    Pignut 14.878591
9   189 2000 20001    Pignut  5.700528
10  189 2000 20001 Bitternut 11.661678
```

But I want just an output like this - duplicate Cnty but different Yr

```
   Cnty   Yr   Plt       Spp       DBH
1   185 1999 20001 Bitternut  3.089619
4   185 2000 20001        WO  5.761556
6    31 1999 20001        WO  7.465489
8    31 2000 20001    Pignut 14.878591
9   189 2000 20001    Pignut  5.700528
```

How can I combine duplicate AND !duplicate for extracting data?
Thanks and all the best
Peter

Answer (score 1):

@ peter below code gives what you want:

```
mydf <- mydf[!duplicated(mydf[,c(1,2)]), ]
mydf


 Cnty   Yr   Plt       Spp    DBH
1  185 1999 20001 Bitternut  3.090
4  185 2000 20001        WO  5.762
6   31 1999 20001        WO  7.465
8   31 2000 20001    Pignut 14.879
9  189 2000 20001    Pignut  5.701
```

Comment: Thanks... Is there a special reason to work with "duplicate" instead of "unique"?